# How to create Array for branches in Jenkins Groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

How to create an Array after git branch -r.
my goal is I want to delete/clean up all branches, which are older than 2 months.

so my Jenkisn Script looks like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label "base" }
    
    

    stages {
        stage('Get All Branches') {
            steps{
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${config.git.credentialsId}", usernameVariable: 'GITUSER', passwordVariable: 'GITPASSWD')]) {
                //      test -d "./.git" && git fetch || git clone -n http://$GITUSER:$GITPASSWD@${srcurl} .
                sh """
                    test -d "./.git" && git fetch || git clone -n gitRepo .
                    git branch -r --sort=-committerdate > .git/branchesList
                """
               
                }    
                
            }
        }
        
        stage('show branches'){
            steps{
                 branchesList = readFile(".git/branchesList").trim()
                    echo branchesList // this line I want to get all branches

             // the Question is How to create an Array from branchesList
            }
        }

       
    }
}


Any solutions?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can readfile in Jenkins using : `readFile(file: '<Filepath>')`.

```
stage('show branches'){
            steps{
                 // Define Array containing branches
                  def BRANCHES = []
                 // Give your path of file. Please change the path according to your requirements

                 def branchesList = readFile(file: 'C:\\Data\\.git\\branchesList.txt')

                 // I assumed your file contains one branch per line, that is why i split with "\n".
                 // You can change this line as per your condition

                 BRANCHES = branchesList.split("\n")                 

                 for (branch in BRANCHES){
                          println ("Branch is : ${branch}") 
                       }
            }
```